# Why my decimal saved as comma not dot in my database

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have table that some fields data type is Decimal like Longitude and Latitude..
Here's my input data into both of that fields, `-6.1897410023321, 106.79859316718436`

But when it saved to my database, it save as `-6,1897410023321, 106,79859316718436`

It change from dot to comma, what i want it still saved with dot not comma..

Here's my migration in laravel 8

```
$table->decimal('pharmacy_long', 11, 7);
$table->decimal('pharmacy_lat', 11, 7);
```

Anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: You can use double `$table->double('pharmacy_long')->nullable();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your decimal seperator and your locale. Please check before saving into database

Comment: Where do i have to check my decimal separator and my locale at laravel?

Comment: on your config file check locale and before saving to db please check your data